# Angular 2 http strongly typed returntype

Tags: angular, angular2-http

In Angular 1 with TypeScript I was able to create services where I know which returntype I will get like an Array of Numbers or a Person Object:

```
public addAges(ages: number[]) : ng.IPromise<number[]> { 
    return this.$http.post('Proxy/AddAges',ages)
                     .then((response: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<number[]>) : number[] 
                         => { return response.data; });
}
```

In Angular 2 I've created the following service which works fine so far, but I don't know where I can set a fully typed returntype like in Angular 1 withe the IPromise and in my case a Array of Persons.

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Response} from 'angular2/http';
import {Person} from './../customDataClasses/Person'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; 

@Injectable()
export class CourseService {
   constructor(private _http: Http) { }
   getPersons(name:string)  {
       return this._http.get(`Home/GetPersons?name=${name}`)
                          .map((res : Response) => res.json());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is what you want:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

...

   getPersons(name:string):Observable<number[]>  {
       return this._http.get(`Home/GetPersons?name=${name}`)
                          .map((res : Response) => res.json());
   }
```

Comment: Yes - but the "Observable" is not found from my TypeScript

Comment: You can import Observables from rxjs/Rx like   import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Rx';

Comment: Do you know if thos has a negative effect on build output size if not imported more selectively? I don't use TS myself and don't have deep knowledge.